# jQuery dialog text issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have the following jQuery dialog exists on my page:

```
<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Empty the recycle bin?">
    <p>
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 20px 0;"></span>
    These items will be permanently deleted and cannot be recovered. Are you sure?
    </p>

</div>
```

In the jQuery UI demo page the text does not appear, yet on my site the text is shown.

I have changed nothing. Anyone else experience this?

[jQuery Link](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-confirmation)

For example I see this text:
`These items will be permanently deleted and cannot be recovered. Are you sure?`

Comment: have you load `jquery.ui.css`?

Comment: try after add this <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

Answer (score 1):

The `div` is hidden when you call `.dialog`. Call it passing the `autoOpen: false` option inside the DOM ready event and call `.dialog('open')` when you want to display it.

```
$("#dialog-confirm").dialog({ 
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    //your buttons and other defined options
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/WHvHF/2/)

Of course, make sure you've included the jQuery lib, jQuery UI and CSS files correctly:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/ui-darkness/jquery-ui.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

**Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/Qd5Xe/3/

Pleas note you are missing the script source I reckon for Jq-UI and Css please see here

Hope it help the cause

**script**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jqueryui.com/demos//css/base.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.21/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://static.jquery.com/ui/css/demo-docs-theme/ui.theme.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**Code**

```
 $(function() {
        // a workaround for a flaw in the demo system (http://dev.jqueryui.com/ticket/4375), ignore!
        $( "#dialog:ui-dialog" ).dialog( "destroy" );

        $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
            resizable: false,
            height:140,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Delete all items": function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                },
                Cancel: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            }
        });
    });​
```

Comment: I have the css referenced but maybe i am missing something. `http://mypage.com/manage/jquery/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.css` i will try the one's you listed as well

Comment: also, let me specify that this works properly. also, once the dialog is opened once, the text at the bottom disappears. so it appears as if it is not being initialized properly?

Comment: Is it possible that my issue comes from the fact that I want the dialog box to be initialized as hidden?